# AngularJS get data from database through controller set as array to show in view

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('Tree', function ($scope,med){
    $scope.med= med.Categories.query();
    //query() have service in which data get from db

    $scope.data = [{ /* i want this id:med.id */          
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'one',
        'parent':0,
        'nodes': [
            {
                'id': 2,
                'title': 'wadood',
                'parent':1
            },
            {
                'id': 3,
                'title': 'nouman',
                'parent':1
            }
        ]
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Can you please brief in few words?

Comment: i want to get id,name from database and and in Json data i want like this #scope.data=[
id: categories.id;
]
// something like this

Comment: Are you able to get the name and id from database?